# Nested attributes in a JSON with Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

I have the following associations:

Campaign **has_many** Trips 
Trip **belongs_to** Campaign 
Trip **has_many** Events 
Event **belongs_to** Trip

In my API I accept POST requests for URLs that look like this:

```
/campaigns/1/trips
```

Where a JSON is passed. The JSON looks like this:

```
{"trip":{"red":3, "blue":400, "events_attributes":[{"distance":300}, {"distance":400}]}}
```

My #create action for the Events Controller looks like this:

```
 def create
     begin
         @campaign = @user.campaigns.find(params[:campaign_id])
         @trip = @campaign.trips.create(params[:trip])
         render json: @trip, :status => :ok
     rescue
         render json: '', :status => :not_found 
     end
 end
```

In my Trip model, I have added this line:

```
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :events
```

So, I was expecting that the Trip would be created with the correspondent Events, but instead of that I am getting a 401 not found.  If I don't pass the events_attributes, the trip gets created correctly.

I have worked out this solution following this question: [Nested object creation with JSON in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845366/nested-object-creation-with-json-in-rails)

Any thoughts on what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, you're rescuing *any* error and returning a 401, which means that you're probably *not seeing* the actual exception that the code is producing. Try removing the `begin/rescue/end` and then including the exception in your question (unless the solution becomes obvious once you see the real error).

Comment: MrTheWalrus, exactly what it was happening. Thank you :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was catching the wrong Exception, and that confused me.

I was getting a mass-assignment error, as events_attributes wasn't accessible from the Trip model, but I was getting that as a not found exception wrongly.

I added this line in Trip model:

```
attr_accessible :events_attributes
```

And it worked like a charm :)

Oh, and btw, I added this in the rescue:

```
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
```