# Rails not recognizing nested JSON objects in POST request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, post, ruby-on-rails-4, thin

Basically, I have two models - Company and Location.

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :locations, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations # Not sure if needed.
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
end
```

When creating a Company (i.e. a POST to `/companies`), I want to be able to create its Locations in the same request. But for some reason, I cannot get Rails to recognize the array of Locations nested inside the Company. It seems to rip the nested JSON array out and place it into the "root" of the JSON request.

Example POST request using cURL:

```
curl -X POST -H "Accept: Application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://example.com/companies -d '{"employee_count":320,"locations":[{"lat":"-47.5", "lon":"120.3"},{"lat":"78.27", "lon":"101.09"}]}'
```

Example server output:

```
Started POST "/companies"
Processing by CompaniesController#create as Application/json
Parameters: {"employee_count"=>320, "locations"=>[{"lat"=>"-47.5", "lon"=>"120.3"}, {"lat"=>"78.27", "lon"=>"101.09"}], "company"=>{"employee_count"=>320}}
```

As you can see, the `locations` array is no longer inside the `company` object, so when CompaniesController#create attempts create the Company instance, it's array of Locations is `nil`. Also, the `employee_count` attribute is repeated twice, which is kind of strange too. **Does anyone know why is this happening and how to fix it?**

For reference, this is what the whitelist in my CompaniesController looks like:

```
params.require(:company).permit(
  :employee_count,
  locations: [:lat, :lon]
)
```

My server is Thin (1.6.2), and it's pretty much an entirely new/default Rails app with no special configurations.

Comment: Check this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845366/nested-object-creation-with-json-in-rails?rq=1 It may help You!

Comment: Nested attributes in strong parameters should be called like this: locations_attributes (both plural).

Comment: @rails4guides.com Exactly!

Comment: You'll have to show us your form & `new` / `create` controller actions -- the problem you have is you're not passing the nested attributes correctly (you have to build ActiveRecord objects when you send the request etc). I can write some help if you show us your controller actions & form

Answer (score 1):

Okay, looks like I needed to rename `locations` to `locations_updates` in my POST request (thanks to the users in the comments who suggested this).

I also needed to encapsulate all attributes in an "outer" `company` object, instead of being at the "root" of the JSON. Example:

```
curl -X POST -H "Accept: Application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://example.com/companies -d '{"company":{"employee_count":320,"locations":[{"lat":"-47.5", "lon":"120.3"},{"lat":"78.27", "lon":"101.09"}]}}'
```