# Rails server keeps responding with "ActionDispatch::ParamsParser::ParseError" with error code 795

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, curl

I'm currently using curl to submit a http request. The curl command looks like this:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"user":{"name":"admin","password":"password"}}' http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users.json
```

The first few lines of the backtrace says this:

```
    ActionDispatch::ParamsParser::ParseError (795: unexpected token at ''{user:{name
:admin,password:password}}''):
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:53:in `resc
ue in parse_formatted_parameters'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:32:in `pars
e_formatted_parameters'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:23:in `call
'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection
_pool.rb:621:in `call'
```

I've looked through my json through many times and checked it on json validator websites and there has been nothing wrong with my json.

What's happening? If more info is needed please ask!

Comment: Remove the `.json` part from the url and try again.

Comment: I tried, but it had the same error.

Comment: try like http://stackoverflow.com/a/22914642/2767755

Comment: Your Curl not looks like a wrong one. I don't know why it is not being able to parse it though.

Comment: Are you authenticating a user or creating a new one?

Comment: I'm trying to create a new user.

Comment: @ArupRakshit I looked through the link but I'm not sure if that applies to my situation.

Comment: I don't know if it even matters but swap single quotes with double ones and vice versa in the user hash.

Comment: Can you give the a more Rails log.. paste the log since when request is entered till the error

Comment: @Marwen Nope, that didn't work.

Comment: @ArupRakshit here's the log that was on the server console http://pastebin.com/xCN5HxKn

Comment: log is not showing what I wanted, it should show there it is a JSON request, which is absent... can you simply pass a smiple JSON like {'a':'2'} and see what is getting in ?

Comment: The server console shows the same thing, but here's what I see right after I submit the curl request. http://pastebin.com/NdPRVmmy

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I never found a solution, but I found an alternative to curl. I now use Postman (on the Chrome app store) to send my POST requests and it's been working really well! Thanks to those who tried to help!